# Using IUnknown derived C++ COM object in VB6

Tags: c++, com, vb6

I have developed a C++ DLL-based COM object that implements some IUnknown derived interface. How can I use it in VB6? Does VB6 support IUnknown based interfaces, or I need to derive from IDispatch?

**UPDATE**

I have not used ATL. The implementation is based on [A very simple COM server without ATL or MFC](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/com_server_without_mfc_atl.aspx) article. Seems like I need to generate a .tlb file for my object?!

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use IDispatch; that's only required for late binding.

To use your object you must add a reference to the object's type library to your VB6 project.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is good that I do not need to implement all this stuff from IDispatch. I have updated my question. Don't you know a way to generate a TLB file without MIDL or MkTypLib?

Comment: Why can't you use MIDL? Defining an interface and coclass in MIDL is a standard part of using COM in C/C++, it doesn't require the use of MFC or ATL.

Comment: It is because (1) I am using MinGW compiler, (2) The MIDL output is littered with meaningless code and comments - I don't like it.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use the .c and .h files MIDL creates; as long as you ensure the interface definitions and GUIDs match what your C++ code uses, it should work. I'm not aware of any other way to generate TLB files.

Answer (score 3):

If the interface is only derived from **IUnknown** and not **IDispatch** , you can use early binding in VB6.